# 2D Tikz Line plot style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to get something that resembles what's on the picture:

[image]

I don't know, it looks so good. Maybe it's because of the font or some trick I have no idea about. So far I was able to plot this:

[image]

CODE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


%%%>
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
  width=\linewidth,
  line width=0.5,
  grid=major, % Display a grid
  tick label style={font=\normalsize},
  legend style={nodes={scale=0.4, transform shape}},
  label style={font=\normalsize},
  legend image post style={mark=triangle},
  grid style={white},
  xlabel={Epochs},
ylabel={RMSE},
   y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=4
 },
  ]
    \addplot[blue] coordinates
      {(100,0.9245) (200,0.9247) (300,0.9243) (400,0.9244) (500,0.9246)(750,0.9253) (1000,0.9248)};
      \addlegendentry{Test}

%     \addplot[no marks,dotted,red] coordinates
%      {(100,0.6949) (200,0.7114) (300,0.7130) (400,0.7134) (500,0.7135 )(750,0.7134) (1000,0.7135)}; 
%      \addlegendentry{Error de entrenamiento}


    \addplot[brown] coordinates
     {(100,0.8814) (200,0.8836) (300,0.8847) (400,0.8855) (500,0.8857)(750,0.8862) (1000,0.8863)};
     \addlegendentry{Test} 

%      \addplot[black,dotted] coordinates
%     {(100,0.7285) (200,0.7564) (300,0.7671) (400,0.7721) (500,0.7745)(750,0.7766) (1000,0.7770)};
%     \addlegendentry{Error de entrenamiento}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

ps: I'd like to plot the exact values on the y-axis. I thought that with `precision=4` it was going to work but it did not.

Comment: Adjust your `ymin = value, ymax = value` may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this something you are after?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


%%%>
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
  width=\linewidth,
  line width=0.5,
  grid=major, % Display a grid
  tick label style={font=\normalsize},
  legend style={nodes={scale=0.4, transform shape}},
  label style={font=\normalsize},
  legend image post style={mark=triangle},
  grid style={white},
  xlabel={Epochs},
ylabel={RMSE},
   y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=4
 },
legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
ymin = 0,
ymax = 1.4,
  ]
    \addplot[blue] coordinates
      {(100,0.9245) (200,0.9247) (300,0.9243) (400,0.9244) (500,0.9246)(750,0.9253) (1000,0.9248)};
      \addlegendentry{Test}

%     \addplot[no marks,dotted,red] coordinates
%      {(100,0.6949) (200,0.7114) (300,0.7130) (400,0.7134) (500,0.7135 )(750,0.7134) (1000,0.7135)}; 
%      \addlegendentry{Error de entrenamiento}


    \addplot[brown] coordinates
     {(100,0.8814) (200,0.8836) (300,0.8847) (400,0.8855) (500,0.8857)(750,0.8862) (1000,0.8863)};
     \addlegendentry{Test} 

%      \addplot[black,dotted] coordinates
%     {(100,0.7285) (200,0.7564) (300,0.7671) (400,0.7721) (500,0.7745)(750,0.7766) (1000,0.7770)};
%     \addlegendentry{Error de entrenamiento}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Based on your input coordinates, this is what would be your rendered output.

Comment: It looks great! Thank you! I think that the author may me using a different font style, maybe? Plus, the line width of the coordinates lines is bigger than the one from the box that is enclosing them.

Comment: Nevermind the last comment. I set `ymin = 0.7 ` `ymax = 0.99,` and your plot looks great now. Thank you very much!